# ASP.NET MVC Optimization: Bundling without minifying?

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization

Is it possible to bundle a set of scripts without minifying them? I just want to combine several third-party script files where I never need the non-minified versions. Some of these have warned against further minification.

Answer (score 7):

Just use the Bundle class and don't specify any transforms.  The ScriptBundle/StyleBundles are automatically registering transforms that do minification.